# What to do if 'sudo make install' does not work for tar.gz files?

Tags: compiling, tar, source-packages

I downloaded the galaxium chat client tar.gz package from google code repositories.

But, I am not able to install it with normal `sudo make install` command as [described in the instructions](http://code.google.com/p/galaxium/wiki/Instructions), it gives an error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

How can I fix this?

---

Content of Makefile.am:

```
SUBDIRS = build src docs

ASSEMBLY_WRAPPER = galaxium
ASSEMBLY_WRAPPER_IN = galaxium.in

PC_FILES =
PC_FILES_IN =

bin_SCRIPTS = $(ASSEMBLY_WRAPPER)

all:

desktopdir = $(datadir)/applications
desktop_DATA = galaxium.desktop

pixmapdir = $(datadir)/pixmaps
pixmap_DATA = galaxium.png

GALAXIUM_LAUNCH_SETUP= \
    cd build && \
    MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=$(MOZILLA_HOME) \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`echo "$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):$(MOZILLA_HOME)" | sed 's/^://g'` \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`echo "$(PKG_CONFIG_PATH):$(MD_PKG_CONFIG_PATH)" | sed 's/^://g'`

GALAXIUM_LAUNCH=$(GALAXIUM_LAUNCH_SETUP) exec -a "galaxium" mono

run: rungalaxium

rungalaxium: $(PROGRAM)
    $(GALAXIUM_LAUNCH) --debug Galaxium.Startup.exe

EXTRA_DIST = $(bin_SCRIPTS) $(desktop_DATA) $(pixmap_DATA)

DISTCLEANFILES = $(bin_SCRIPTS)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 3):

When a build fails, it is *almost always* necessary (or at least *very helpful*) to provide *all* the information from the terminal, including from when you ran `./configure`. When this exceeds the maximum length of an Ask Ubuntu post or becomes excessively long (which often happens), you can use http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link.

In general, if you *just* ran `sudo make install` and you didn't run `./configure` and `make` first, run them (in that order).

*Some* unpacked source code archives will let you run `sudo make install` without having explicitly run `make`. Some will not. Either way, you should run `make` as a separate step before running `sudo make install`. Sometimes you have to, and even when you do not, this lets you see any warning messages shown at the end before installing, and it keeps the files created inside the source directory owned by you, and not root.

Answer (score 1):

The [actual instructions for Galaxium (hidden in the `INSTALL` file)](http://code.google.com/p/galaxium/source/browse/trunk/INSTALL) have an extra step:

```
as normal user:
sh autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make

as root:
make install
```

If you haven't run the autogen, you won't have things in place for the make targets. That might explain why it's not working.